# slow framerate in pygame only during a specific function or similar effect?

Tags: python, string, pygame, frame-rate

Is there a way to lower the frame rate of my program only when a specific function is running? I've made a class that renders text on the screen one character at time to simulate typing. As expected, each character renders at the speed of the framerate, which is not the effect I want. Changing framerate helps, but I don't want to affect any other animations I may have. Is there a way to do this or maybe a work around I'm not thinking of? `pygame.wait` hangs the entire program.

```py
# simulate printing text one character at a time on the screen
class TextPrint:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, fontSize, fontColor, string, gameSurface):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Lucida Console', fontSize)
        self.fontColor = fontColor
        self.displayText = string
        self.active = False # is the text area currently in use
        self.activeIndex = 0 # index that is being added to current render
        self.gameSurface = gameSurface
    
    def update(self):
        self.surf = self.font.render(self.displayText[:self.activeIndex], True, self.fontColor)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(x=self.xpos,y=self.ypos)
        if self.activeIndex > len(self.displayText): pass
        else: self.activeIndex += 1

    def draw(self):
        self.gameSurface.blit(self.surf, self.rect)
```

Comment: You don't have to change your animation every frame. Set up a timer, where you add delta time (like the output of `pygame.time.Clock.tick()`) to a variable, and when it crosses a threshold, reset it to zero and advance activeIndex by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you can try is, have a variable like `count = 50` and then have a function which is called once in the game loop and decreases the value of `count` by 1, and then when `count` has a value of 0, then you can type out a character, then reset `count` to 50, and repeat the whole process until all your text is printed out.

This was my first answer on stack overflow though, I answered this cause I have already implemented such a thing.

Comment: instead of using such a counter you may want to use [`timer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) and a custom event instead and when the event is detected add the character